# ReactJS: form sends wrong date value to database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, forms, reactstrap

I'm trying to send data to the database with a Reactstrap form and everything is being sent correctly, except the date value. Whatever date I put is saved as `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00` on MongoDB and I have no idea why.

When I send everything through Postman, it saves the correct value, but I want to submit it from the form.

Form date field:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
   <FormGroup>
      <Label className="lead">Horário local da leitura</Label>
      <Input type="text" name="hora_leitura" required />
```

onSubmit function

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const {
      hora_leitura, pressao_atm, temp_ar, temp_min, temp_max,
      umid_rel, umid_min, rad_solar, chuva_ac_dia, inten_vento,
      direc_vento,
    } = this.state;
    const newEntry = {
      hora_leitura, pressao_atm, temp_ar, temp_min, temp_max,
      umid_rel, umid_min, rad_solar, chuva_ac_dia, inten_vento,
      direc_vento,
    };

    // Add entry via addEntry action
    this.props.addEntry(newEntry);
  };
```

onChange function

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

POST Entry API code:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const {
    hora_leitura, pressao_atm, temp_ar, temp_min, temp_max, umid_rel,
    umid_min, rad_solar, chuva_ac_dia, inten_vento, direc_vento,
  } = req.body;

  Entry.findOne({ hora_leitura }).then((isMatch) => {
    if (isMatch)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "Uma entrada com essa data já existe" });
    else {
      const newEntry = new Entry({
        hora_leitura, pressao_atm, temp_ar, temp_min, temp_max, umid_rel,
        umid_min,rad_solar, chuva_ac_dia, inten_vento, direc_vento,
      });
      newEntry.save().then((entry) => res.json(entry));
    }
  });
});
```

No idea why it doesn't send the correct date. If you could please help and maybe explain your answer it would be great.

**Edit:**

On my `EntryModal` class state, I have this

```
state = {
    modal: false,
    added: false,
    hora_leitura: new Date(), 
    pressao_atm: 0,
    temp_ar: 0,
    temp_min: 0,
    temp_max: 0,
    umid_rel: 0,
    umid_min: 0,
    rad_solar: 0,
    chuva_ac_dia: 0,
    inten_vento: 0,
    direc_vento: "",
    msg: null,
  };
```

and I put a `console.log` right above calling `addEntry` on `onSubmit()` and it showed `hora_leitura` as the exact date the form was sent, instead of the date I inserted. I don't know if my code is reading the correct date value on `onChange`.

Comment: How do you save your date in the state or how do you pick it to be more accurate?

Comment: @Slavian at first I set the date: 0 in the state and then it should update to the new value by  `this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });` on the onChange method in the same class as the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I noticed that, to change the value I set on the state, I had to call `onChange` on the element, as I had on every input on the form, but not on `<Input type="text" name="hora_leitura" required />`, so whatever value I put in this input wouldn't matter.

I just changed the input to this:

```
<Input
  type="text"
  name="hora_leitura"
  placeholder="2020-06-12T09:00:00.000"
  onChange={this.onChange} // this is what was missing
  required
/>
```

And it worked perfectly.